# Uniquness check without DB constraints

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications

For example, we have a table (login, hash). We have no `unique` constraint on login column, but we should keep it unique (just for example).
When a new user registers, we check if entered login is free.
If it's a java web app deployed to Tomcat, that has thread pool, then those checks might be processed parallel, right? How to ensure uniqueness then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pessimist lock in the table, that will lock the table and you can check if has and save, so other thread won't be able to change that table for this time being. But I think that is a really bad way to do things, why not use DB constraints ?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't have a good solution without database constraints here.

Without a constraint in a multi-threaded environment you'll need some common resource to synchronize your threads on. A thread would acquire the mutex, check if login is free (using a `SELECT`) and then `INSERT` a new record if it was free. No other thread should be able to do this at the same time - this is why you need synchronization here.

This will work iff all your threads have access to this mutex and if it is guaranteed that noone else can access the database at the same time.

The first problem appears if you have, for instance several machines which access the same database. Threads running on different machines will not have access to the same mutex so they will happily insert in your table in parallel.

The other problem that if someone logs in to database and creates records in that table directly, such inserts may happen exactly between SELECT and INSERT executed from your code. So synchronization in code won't help here.

A further option is locking the whole table, but that's even worse. You'll need to very reliably release the lock otherwise you're risking stalling the whole system.